# How to print stdout & stderr of failed job in GNU parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'm invoking GNU parallel on a bunch of commands using `parallel --keep-order --line-buffer --halt 2`. Every once in a while one of the commands fails, and GNU parallel prints:

```
 parallel: This job failed:
    <failing command comes here>
```

Is there any way to to print the stdout and stderr of ONLY the failed job whenever this happens?

Answer (score 3):

`neno` (no-error-no-output) does that:

```
neno 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2; false'
neno 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2; true'
```

https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/neno

So:

```
parallel --halt 2 neno ...
```

Comment: Thanks for developing  GNU parallel